# Confused using ftp_get in php

Tags: php, ftp, get

Im confused by an estate agency vebra import script that worked fine before it was moved to a different server however now this seems to not work at all.

Does anyone have any idea why i would get the following warnings...

> Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Opening data channel for file
>   transfer. in
>   /home/username/public_html/includes/cron/import/vebra-import.php on
>   line 37
>
> Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Transfer OK in
>   /home/username/public_html/includes/cron/import/vebra-import.php on
>   line 37

here is the ftp connection code:

```
  $ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_host, 21) or die("FTP Connection Error");

  ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) or die("Can't Connect to FTP");

  $ftpdir = ftp_nlist($ftp, "/");


  if(!empty($ftpdir) && count($ftpdir) > 0) {

  foreach($ftpdir as $ftpfile) {

      if(preg_match("/\.txt$/", $ftpfile)) {
          $getfile = ftp_get($ftp, $csv_dir.$ftpfile, $ftpfile, FTP_BINARY);
          if($getfile){
              $downloaded++;
          }
          $total++;

      }

  }

  }
  ftp_close($ftp);
```

Furthermore, it seems to be intermittent, and sometimes this executes successfully other times it fails with the above errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your server is not in a passive mode, and add this code to process:

```
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
```

For more information look at passive mode on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php
Passive mode uses the data initiated by the client rather than the server. So this is why you can't put on server. If this is not set it will fail.

NOTE: Set `ftp_pasv()` function after `ftp_login()` function.

Comment: I tried this but this gave further errors but for some reason that did the trick? bit of a strange one. Thanks for your help

Comment: php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) was the error

Comment: Huh, this should be work, try upgrade FTP ver or bypass firewall, look this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47110

Comment: ah it is working now, but when i first tried using ftp_pasv() this was the error i had which is why i took it out. But like i say its working now so thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

After using ftp_pasv () the problem was still occurring. I found out that the number of requests to the server caused a problem with the firewall (I used a foreach() loop to scroll through multiple files). Because I did not have permission to modify the firewall rules, I added a sleep () in my script between the requests.

This is how i fixed the warning.